# Dynamic Resources and Merged Dictionaries levels

Tags: wpf, dictionary

I have the following configuration of Resource Dictionaries:

ColorsDic.xaml contains

```
<Color x:Key="MyColor">#FF39ADFB</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="GenericBackColor" Color="{DynamicResource  MyColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlDark" Color="{DynamicResource MyColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlLight" Color="{DynamicResource MyColor}" opacity="0.3"/>
```

MainDic.xaml contains

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries >
  <ResourceDictionary Source="./Recursos/ColorsDic.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries >

<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GenericBackColor}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Background,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource BackToForeColor}}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Now the problem:
I'd made an user control that includes a button with the style defined before and its main background color is set to "ControlDark" solid brush. When I change the value of "MyColor" from the application main window, button takes all changes but not the background of the user control. 
What is wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the button Style's background property setter to DynamicResource from StaticResource.

If you're trying to change colors at run time a static resource only grabs it resource when instantiated and doesn't update when the resource is changed.

EDIT: 
If your issue is with the user control's background you can set the background of the user control using a border:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Pick a backgound color here-->
    <Border Background="Red"/>

    <Button Content="TEST" Height="20" Width="50"/>
</Grid>
```

Or set your background on the User Control to transparent if the user control does not need a background and only the controls inside of it do:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
         Background="Transparent">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="TEST" Height="20" Width="50"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: But I think that button is working properly...I need the whole control works like the button inside....